# Chai: how to test for undefined with 'should' syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, chai

Building on [this](http://www.alexrothenberg.com/2013/08/06/how-to-unit-test-an-angular-app.html) tutorial testing an angularjs app with chai, I want to add a test for an undefined value using the "should" style. This fails:

```
it ('cannot play outside the board', function() {
  scope.play(10).should.be.undefined;
});
```

with error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined", but the test passes with the "expect" style:

```
it ('cannot play outside the board', function() {
  chai.expect(scope.play(10)).to.be.undefined;
});
```

How can I get it working with "should"?

Comment: It is easy if you will use "assert", you can do it as `assert.isUndefined(scope.play(10))`

Comment: I don't like any of the answers here, so I went with just using `expect` for undefined checks, `should` for everything else 

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This is one of the disadvantages of the should syntax. It works by adding the should property to all objects, but if a return value or variable value is undefined, there isn't a object to hold the property.

The [documentation](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/) gives some workarounds, for example:

```
var should = require('chai').should();
db.get(1234, function (err, doc) {
  should.not.exist(err);
  should.exist(doc);
  doc.should.be.an('object');
});
```

Comment: `should.not.exist` will validate if the value is `null` so this answer is not correct. @daniel has the answer below: `should.equal(testedValue, undefined);`. That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I come to this answer (not the docs ) on a monthly basis :-)

Answer (score 62):

```
should.equal(testedValue, undefined);
```

as mentioned in chai documentation

Comment: omg, what is there to explain? You expect testedValue to === undefined so you test it. A lot of developers first put testedValue first and then chain it with should and it  ends up with error...

Comment: This doesn't work out of the box and it isn't found in [the API documentation for `.equal()`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal). I can understand why @OurManInBananas asked for an explanation. It's an unexpected use of should as a function accepting two arguments, instead of the expected chained method form accepting a single argument for the expected value. You can only achieve this by importing/requiring and assigning an invoked version of `.should()` as described in the accepted answer by @DavidNorman and in this [documentation](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should-extras).

Comment: I think you'll find that that `.equal` syntax produces much better error messages because it allows you to output messages that are more descriptive when things fail

Comment: `should().equal(value1, value2)`

Answer (score 18):

```
(typeof scope.play(10)).should.equal('undefined');
```

Answer (score 18):

Test for undefined

```
var should = require('should');
...
should(scope.play(10)).be.undefined;
```

Test for null

```
var should = require('should');
...
should(scope.play(10)).be.null;
```

Test for falsy, i.e. treated as false in conditions

```
var should = require('should');
...
should(scope.play(10)).not.be.ok;
```

Comment: Not especially useful or intuitive, but that's clever!

Comment: not useful? It's the best answer for undefined testing in bdd style IMO, however it needs to install other npm package (the should package), and I don't think that worth installing other package just for that, awesome answer though

Answer (score 12):

I struggled to write the should statement for undefined tests. The following doesn't work.

```
target.should.be.undefined();
```

I found the following solutions.

```
(target === undefined).should.be.true()
```

if can also write it as a type check

```
(typeof target).should.be.equal('undefined');
```

Not sure if the above is the right way, but it does work.

[According to Post from ghost in github](https://github.com/tj/should.js/issues/27)

Comment: It's worth noting that using this syntax can result in JavaScript interpreting the parenthesized expression as an attempt to invoke the previous line as a function (if you're not ending lines with a semicolon).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
it ('cannot play outside the board', function() {
   expect(scope.play(10)).to.be.undefined; // undefined
   expect(scope.play(10)).to.not.be.undefined; // or not
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I'm doing in the second attempt above. I'd like to understand how to do it with the [should](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should) syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget about a combination of `have` and `not` keywords:

```
const chai = require('chai');
chai.should();
// ...
userData.should.not.have.property('passwordHash');
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @david-norman is correct as per the documentation, I had a few issues with setup and instead opted for the following.

(typeof scope.play(10)).should.be.undefined;

Comment: `typeof` operator returns a **string**; so this assertion could not be passed; cuz `'undefined' !== undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function result in `should()` and test for a type of "undefined":

```
it ('cannot play outside the board', function() {
  should(scope.play(10)).be.type('undefined');
});
```